# Indexer in Azure Cognitive Search service not being created

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I'm trying to create an Indexer in Azure Cognitive Search service. but it not being created, it does not appear in indexer, I have many indexers created by others, I have also created indexers previously and it worked fine. but from few days ago new indexer is not being created even after authentication using device code is done. it still not appears in indexer list.

tried using REST API and UI also.
also tried using new resource group.

Comment: can you update your question with error details, code and any other relevant info that can help hi reproduce the issue.

Comment: it's not returning any kind of error, normally when we create indexer it gets created but it doesn't run successfully. so, we have call REST API to get status which will response with JSON in which we will have error message with device login URL and a Code. then we open URL add code perform auth. after that indexer runs successfully.

in my case indexer is not being created. when I call get status API for it will response with URL code which get authenticated successfully. but indexer is not being created...

Comment: Looks like I have similar issue. Being authenticated by device code but indexer never created.

Comment: @user2250152 Please Updated here if you get any solution. Thanks!

Comment: @HacktymusPrime I've no solution so far.

Comment: We are taking a look at the symptoms to understand the issue. Since this is a feature in preview, it is supported on best effort only, so it may take some time. Thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very specific of your use case and that would require the support team to review for configuration and understanding if this an issue specific of your search deployment or that specific indexer. Please open a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Thanks

Comment: in select dropdown of Resource there is no search service available (only Azure Open AI services shown).

Comment: Hi, I have very similar issue, it seems that indexer is broken. Support ticket is not allowed for all subscriptions. Check the comment in the answer, the issue probably affects more people: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77437295/2250152